# Как запустить Wine на Kali linux под Android?

Tags: linux, wine

Установил на телефон Kali Linux через Andronix
Установил Wine и Playonlinux.
Не получается установить .exe приложения через Wine. При попытке установить любое приложение через playonlinux (даже из родного списка) получаю ошибку:

```
Wine seems to have crashed
```

При попытке установить через Wine (через терминал) получаю ошибку:

```
0020:err:plugplay:deviceloop_thread Can't init SDL: Could not initialize UDEV
0009:err:module:__wine_process_init L"Z:\\root\\Downloads\\GoogleAdsEditorSetup.exe" not supported on this system
```

Куда копать?

Comment: на телефоне наверно у Вас arm процессор, а приложение, которое Вы устанавливаете - под x86 платотформу?

Comment: Всё верно. Но установлены из официального репозитория kali linux. Под arm64. Explorer в Wine работает нормально. Через него получается запустить пакеты .msi и даже идёт установка (но послу установки программы не появляются на C:). По идее, раз playonlinux можно установить из официального репозитория, то должны запускаться программы. Но нет.

Comment: Ну если exe-файл собран для x86, то на arm64 вы его конечно никак не запустите

Comment: установка в большинстве случаев - это просто распаковка архива (кроме особых случаев, когда в процессе инсталяции запускаются бинарник с инсталлятора). Отвечая на вопрос в вопросе - Вы занимаетесь садомазохизмом. не делайте так.

Comment: @andreymal например notepad.exe запускается и работает нормально.

Comment: @DenKuzmin а откуда вы взяли notepad.exe?

Comment: @andreymal из Wine. Запустил через explorer.exe

Comment: @DenKuzmin ну очевидно, что разработчики Wine позаботились о том, чтобы пересобрать свой собственный notepad.exe под arm64. А теперь попробуйте скопировать notepad.exe с какого-нибудь обычного компьютера с виндой — и он не запустится, потому что x86

Comment: @andreymal скажите, а это может помочь https://github.com/AndreRH/hangover/blob/master/README.md ?

Comment: @DenKuzmin по сути это просто использование виртуальной машины с эмуляцией x86 процессора. Может и поможет, но будет очень медленно

Comment: @andreymal как это запустить?

Comment: Просто скажи какую именно цель ты хочешь достичь в самом конце. Запустить Ведьмака? Не получится. Запустить Ворд? Не получится. Запустить вайршарк? Воспользуйся официальным портом, если он есть.

Comment: @don Rumata Запустить google ads editor. Почему не получится Ворд запустить?

Comment: Эээ. Это ж вроде виндовая прога, если Хабр не врёт. Зачем мабила-то? Ворд под вайном x86 запускается только 2007-й версии без проблем. Дальше - только с бубном. А ты вообще на арме хочешь.